# ListPicker Message.Attach error in Caliburn.Micro

Tags: windows-phone-7, caliburn.micro, listpicker

I'm having the following XAML code on WP7:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ListPickerBwFactors" ItemsSource="{Binding BwFactors}" 
                            cal:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged]=[Action ChangeBinarizeFactor(ListPickerBwFactors.ItemSelected)]">
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

I'm getting the error:**Target must be a FrameworkElement or a CollectionViewSource**

All I want to do is to pass to my VM, the SelectedItem from ListPicker.
What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current version of Silverlight on the WP7 is based off Silverlight 3, one of the major restrictions was that you could only Bind to dependency properties on a FrameworkElement or a CollectionViewSource (as opposed to say a DependencyObject in WPF).

The reason you're seeing that error for this piece of code is that behind the scenes the Message.Attach attached dependency property makes use of Behaviors, (specifically ActionMessage) which aren't FrameworkElements.

Caliburn is trying to set up a Binding from ListPickerBwFactors.ItemSelected to the Parameter of the ActionMessage and failing. It basically means parameters in Caliburn aren't much use at the moment. You'll need to bind the SelectedItem to a property on the ViewModel instead.

On the bright side, the "Mango" release of WP7 will update Silverlight on the phone to 4, where this problem is resolved.

Comment: I see.So basically, I have to use only Databinding, but I'm loosing all the Caliburn messaging architecture. 
Thanks  !

Comment: Not all of it, you can still use conventions to wire to action, it's just those actions can't have parameters at the moment. I believe there are conventions you can create to binding to the SelectedItem for a ListPicker